# How to include recent activity of a Facebook Page into a website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I see that are lots of topics with Facebook integration but I haven't found what I was looking for.
I have a Facebook Page and a website. I want to include recent activity from my facebook page into my website. 
I found this code

```
<div class="fb-activity" data-site="www.site.ro" data-width="160" data-height="300"  data-header="true" data-border-color="#ffffff" data-recommendations="false"></div>
```

but this will get recent activity of my friends and does not have nothing to do with my facebook page :|

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [Like Box plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/): It shows a feed of your Page's wall and allows users to like your Facebook page directly from your web page

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to embed code in your web page so to display Activity Feed. If my assumption is correct, here is your answer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/activity

Answer (score 0):

This example (originally from Stack Overflow Documentation) shows how to obtain the Facebook access tokens and the using the tokens to fetch FB feeds and data to display ion your website:

**Example:**

A live example is available in

> https://newtonjoshua.com

**Introduction to Graph API:**

The Graph API is the primary way to get data in and out of Facebook's platform. It's a low-level HTTP-based API that you can use to query data, post new stories, manage ads, upload photos and a variety of other tasks that an app might need to do.

**FaceBook Apps:**

> https://developers.facebook.com

Create a Facebook app. You will get an `App_Id` and `App_Secret`

**Graph API Explorer:**

> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/`{{App_Id}}`/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed&version=v2.8

You will get an `access_token` which is short lived. So this will be our `short_lived_access_token`.

note: while creating access token select all the fb fields that you require.This will give permission to the access token to fetch those fields.

**Access Token Extension:**

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=**{{App_Id}}**&client_secret=**{{App_Secret}}**&fb_exchange_token=**{{short-lived-access_token}}**

You will get an `access_token` with a validity of 2 months.

**Access Token Debugger:**

> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken?q=**{{access_token}}**&version=v2.8

you can check check the details of the `access_token`.

**Facebook SDK for JavaScript:**

Include the below JavaScript in your HTML to asynchronously load the SDK into your page

```
<script>
        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                return;
            }
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

**Graph API:**

Let's make an API call to get our FB id, profile pic, cover pic and feeds.

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '{{App_Id }}',
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.7'
    });
    FB.api(
        '/me',
        'GET', {
            fields: 'id,picture{url},cover,feed',
            access_token: {{access_token}}
        },
        function (response) {
        if (response.error) {
                console.error(response.error.message);
            }
            if (response.picture.data.url) {
                profilePic = response.picture.data.url;
            }
            if (response.cover.source) {
                coverPic = response.cover.source;
            }
            if (response.feed.data) {
        feeds = response.feed.data;
                feeds.forEach(function (feed) {
            // view each feed content
                });
            }
            if (response.feed.paging.next) {
                nextFeedPage = response.feed.paging.next;
        // a request to nextFeedPage will give the next set of feeds
            }

        }
    );
};

</script>
```

Use the Graph API Explorer to design your query that should be entered in the 'fields' (eg: 'id,picture{url},cover,feed')

Now you can fetch your facebook data from Facebook Graph API using your access_token.

refer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/

note: Your `access_token` will expire in 2 months. Create a new access_token after that.